# Bootstrap - Remove Input Control lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I have an input field. I am trying to make it so only the bottom border of the input field is visible. However, as you can see in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ce2o76wd/1/) I've created, I've been unable to remove the left, right, and top borders. Currently, I'm using the following CSS:

```
.my-input-field {
  border-top:0px; 
  border-right:0px; 
  border-left:0px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #2d2d2d;
  outline:none;
}

.my-input-field:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

But, there is still a slight shadow or something around the input box. How do I remove that shadow or border around the control. I can't figure out what it is or what's causing it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: simply add `box-shadow: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-shadow:none;`, this solve your problem because the border that you see is just a CSS3 shadow and not a solid border.

Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/ce2o76wd/2/).

If you want to know more about `box-shadow` read [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-box-shadows/).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove form-control from your class and use only .my-input-field, any way this is the solution:

```
.my-input-field:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, simply add the `box-shadow: none;` and I just added an extra feature here that removes the blue glow around the box on focus. See the code below:

```
.my-input-field {
  border-top:0px; 
  border-right:0px; 
  border-left:0px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #2d2d2d;
  outline:none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.my-input-field:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {   
  border-color: rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-gXt9imSW0VcJVHezoNQsP+TNrjYXoGcrqBZJpry9zJt8PCQjobwmhMGaDHTASo9N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>something</title>

    <!--style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
    
</head>

<body>
    
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class="form-controll form-controll-sm">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```